# Stop a tag from firing if an element is visible in google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I made a sign up event that after pressing signup button checks the validity of input data like email and if conditions are true fires an event.But if user enters a previously used email an element shows up and displays an error. I can detect the error message by gtm through element visibilty trigger but I cant stop my event from firing if error shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DOM type variable with a CSS selector for your element. This variable will be undefined until the element is actually displayed. Name it e.g. "errorVisible". Then add an execption trigger to your tags. Set it to "custom event", tick the "use regex" checkbox and enter ".*" (regex for any number of any character). In the "this events fires" section select "some events". In the filter settings, select the "errorVisible" variable created above, use "does not equal" as match type and "undefined" (without quotes) as value. This trigger will fire every time the error element is visible, and if used as exception trigger will prevent tags to be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of the answer by Eike Pierstorff (*Sorry Eike, I would upvote you but I don't have the rep score yet*)

I created an Element Visibility *variable*, which outputs true or false. In my case it was for a toggle, and the only change indicator in the DOM is the class name of the icon associated with the clicked toggle.

**So, I made the variable, then added it to the trigger as:**

variable -- equals -- true for my close toggle event

and

variable -- equals -- false  for my open toggle event.

You should be able to make a similar element visible variable, which I found much easier to work with than an element visible trigger.